# How to interract with dynamically added controls in a formview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, formview, page-lifecycle

I am doing the following:

I have a formview, within which a small section is created dynamically. In practice, some controls are added or not, depending on the value of one particular column of my dataItem.

So, my page loads, my formview binds, and during the formview_DataBound(), I create my additionnal controls (labels and textboxes mainly) and assign them values from the dataItem.

Now, that's all fine and dandy in read-only mode, but it's not OK in edit or create mode.
For example in edit mode: If I edit one of my added textboxes, when I press my button in order to update my data, a postback happens.
And by the time I enter formview_ItemUpdating(), the controls haven't been recreated yet, as it happens before the formview's databinding.
So I cannot read the values of these controls and subsequently can't complete my update.

Same thing happens in create mode of course…

Is there a way to manage that properly ?

Comment: could you provide some sample code to better illustrate your problem?

Comment: It's possible to correctly handle dynamic controls in webforms, but it's a pain in the backside. Avoid it if at all possible. I myself have often worked around the need by having controls that are part of the `aspx` page (so not dynamic) which are in turn hidden when they should not be filled in. It may feel *wrong*, but it will let you get on with your work instead of having to reinvent/re-implement the control initialization that the ASP.Net webforms framework does.